# Riparian corridor delineation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, watershed, upstream

I am trying to delineate the riparian corridors using GRASS in R. But I am having some issues.

So is there a plugin in QGIS using which I can extract riparian corridors using the already available upstream corridors?

Comment: Do you simply want to extract a buffer zone around lines (rivers)? If so, just use the buffer tool (native in QGIS) with the buffer size corresponding to your needs.

Comment: Well, I have  some sampling points, SO, I wanted to extract 10Km buffer zone along the line (stream) and with 150m width

Comment: What do your sampling points represent? Are they located inside the buffer (riparian corridor), or are they part of the streams? Your problem does not seem difficult, but you should tell us *exactly* what you currently have if you want a useful answer (especially since most of us don't have any environmental background).

Comment: OKay, I have a separate sampling points shapefile which is snapped on to lines. Now I want to extract the upstream riparrian corridor for each of these sampling point. after extracting these riparian corridors, I will have to extract the landuse (from another .tif file, ofcourse) in these riparian corridor polygons; which is my final output.

Comment: I am still not sure what you mean. It sounds like you are asking for upstream, flow to be created (hence these become pour points in an r.outlets process) I think you want this https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.water.outlet.html then a buffer. Get your upstream stream from points then buffer, right?

Comment: There is no plugin specifically for riparian corridor extraction. I think that answers your question in full. But as said. If you explain what you are actually trying to achieve then you might get an answer that provides solution. Or use GRASS and R: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1364815214003077

Comment: @Vensanto I am actually workin gon the same project  with that paper. But my script has alot of error. so, I thought to search if there is any other option rather debugging those errors.

Comment: I have all the flow and accumulation maps using r.watershed, r.water.outlet. Now I should just extract riparian corridors, where my scripts has lot of bugs as already explained.